# If I pair numbers from a set such that EACH number is in EXACTLY $x$ unique pairs, what values can $x$ be?

Tags: combinatorics

For example, with the set $S=\{\ 1\  ,\  2\  ,\  3\  ,\  4\ ,\  5\ ,\  6\ \}$, I'm able to have:

Each number is in exactly 1 unique pair. $(\ 1, 2\ )\ \  (3,4)\ \ (5,6)$

Each number is in exactly 2 unique pairs. $(1,2)\  (1,3)\  (2,3)\  (4,5)\  (4,6)\  (5,6)$

Each number is in exactly 5 unique pairs. $\ (1,2)\  (1,3)\  (1,4)\ (1,5)\  (1,6)\  (2,3)\  (2,4)\  (2,5)\  (2,6)\  (3,4)\  (3,5)\  (3,6)\  (4,5)\  (4,6)\  (5,6)\ $

For small sets, one can write these out rather easily (but tediously), but how can I determine what $x$ numbers of unique pairs are valid for a set $S$ with an arbitrary number of elements $n$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do ALL numbers of the set have to used?

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not complete: if you take all possible pairs (your last example) and you remove all pairs from your first or second example, then you get a pairing where each element appears in 4 respectively 3 unique pairs. Thus in this case it is possible for each number of pairs between 1 and 5 (and actually also 0).

Your question is naturally asked in the language of graph theory. Take the set $S$ as the vertices of a graph, and take the pairs you pick as undirected edges in this graph. Then the fact that a node appears in exactly $x$ pairs means that it is an $x$-regular graph. Thus you can rephrase the question: does there exist an $x$-regular graph on $n$ vertices? This question is already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/11404/75429). To summarize: this is possible if and only if at least one of $n$ and $x$ is even.